# How to access HTML text using Selenium /Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <h2>TEST1</h2>
    <p>
        TEST2<br />
        TEST3<br />
        TEST4
    </p>
    <p>
       TEST5 <strong><em>TEST6</em></strong>
    **** This is the text to be captured ****
    </p>
</div>
```

I want to access the text " This is the text to be captured " using selenium on Python.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Wgat did yiu try so far? Please post your attempts when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath, for simplicity you can use some extension in chrome to determine xpath easily. I hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

XPath 1.0 solution :

```
//strong/following::text()[normalize-space()]
```

Output :   `**** This is the text to be captured ****`